# PWM using thread

Tags: multithreading, matlab, pwm

Am modelling an inverter with 5 switches controlled by multi-reference single carrier SPWM. I need to generate pulses for 5 switches at a time using a MATLAB function block. Since it cannot be executed one at a time we need to use parallel programming to which I am new. So please suggest alternatives or parallel programming methods for generating PWM.

The output of the PWM generator is attached

[image: Switching pattern for generating 5-level PWM]

The reference signals had the same frequency and amplitude and were in phase with an offset value that was equivalent to the amplitude of the carrier signal. The reference signals were each compared with the carrier signal.Two reference signals Vref1 and Vref2 will take turns to be compared with the carrier signal at a time. If Vref1 exceeds the peak amplitude of the carrier signal Vcarrier, Vref2 will be compared with the carrier signal until it reaches zero. At this
point onward, Vref1 takes over the comparison process until it exceeds Vcarrier. This will lead to a switching pattern as shown in image. Switches S1- S3 will be switching at the rate of the carrier signal frequency while S4 and S5 will operate at a frequency equivalent to the fundamental frequency.

Comment: Can you provide more information. The inputs and outputs of the block for example.

Comment: Pattern and description added.